# Working with Boolean fields on Mongoid

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb, mongoid

I create a Model that has a Boolean field, but when catch the value it gave me 1 or 0. I discover that it's because BSON type for Boolean is "\x00" and "\x01".

So my question is, how can I get the "boolean" value of the field? Do I need to do a method on a model or a controller that returns me true if value is 1 or false if 0? Or will Mongoid do this for me?

**Mongoid Version:** 4.0.0 38de2e9

**EDIT**
Mongo Shell

```
db.feedbacks.find().limit(1).pretty()
{
  "_id" : ObjectId("52290a2f56de969f8d000001"),
  "like" : "1",
...
}
```

**Explain:**

I create a app with scaffold:

> rails g scaffold Feedback like:Boolean

When I insert a new record, in Mongo the Document stay as I sad.
When I do Feedback.first, the field like in Model has the "0" or "1" value.

```
class Feedback
  include Mongoid::Document
  include Mongoid::Timestamps

  field :comment, type: String

  field :like, type: Boolean


  def isLike?
    like=="1"
  end

end
```

This is the repo:
https://github.com/afucher/4kFeedback/blob/master/app/models/feedback.rb

Comment: Could you add the code of your Feedback model ?

Comment: Edited, put also the github repo.

Comment: I cloned the repo, and created a Feedback instance from the rails console. Everything is ok (`feedback=Feedback.create!(like: true) ; feedback.reload ; feedback.like #=> true`)

Comment: Hmmm...I think so, that is the checkbox on the view generated by scaffold =/ The checkbox value is 0 or 1, but I need to treat this on the controller??

Comment: Did you try to explicitly specify a value for the checkbox in your view (let say "true" or "yes") ?

Comment: Thanks Jef, after you sad this, I find in the checkbox documentation that I need to pass the default value that I want...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can resolve my problem, reading the check_box documentation:
http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper/check_box

The default value of Check Box is "0" or "1". To change this value, is just pass the values that you want to the tag:

```
check_box(object_name, method, options = {}, checked_value = "1", unchecked_value = "0")
```

So, I change to this:

```
<%= f.check_box :like,{}, "true", "false" %>
```

Thanks Jef for help me!!

Answer (score 4):

Mongoid handles that in a transparent manner if you use the `Boolean` type. Checkout the [documentation](http://mongoid.org/en/mongoid/docs/documents.html#fields).

**EDIT** :

From the rails console (in an app with an `Indicator` model defining a field `global` of type `Boolean`) :

```
Indicator.first.global?
# => true
Indicator.first.global?.class
# => TrueClass
```

The equivalent from the mongo shell :

```
> db.indicators.find().limit(1).pretty()
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("52319eeb56c02cc74200009c"),
    ...
    "global" : true,
    ...
}
```

**EDIT**

The [spec](https://github.com/mongoid/mongoid/blob/master/spec/mongoid/extensions/boolean_spec.rb) for the Boolean extension clearly shows that for any of `true, "true", "t", "yes", "y", 1, 1.0` on the MongoDB side you'll get a `TrueClass` instance. Same for false.

Comment: And in Mongo? How is the Document? global: 1 or global:true ??

Comment: Hmm ok, but I use scaffold, and I don't know why, when I create a new Document, it creates with value "1" or "0"..

Comment: I'm not sure I understand where your problem exactly is, sorry if it's the case. The BSON spec states that boolean are stored as `\x00` and `\x01`. Mongoid (>=3) uses Moped as its underlying driver that handles Ruby/BSON conversions transparently.

Comment: For sure. What version of Mongoid are you using ?